# Получить значения атрибутов

Tags: c#, test-automation, xunit

Столкнулся с проблемой.
Нужно получить результаты которые отображаются при наведении курсора. Но не знаю как получить эту информацию так как когда убираю курсор локаторы элемента сразу пропадают.
Буду рад любой помощи.

Когда курсор наведен
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Когда курсор не наведен
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Там выполняется j's, поставьте точку останова на выполнение.

Comment: Не понимаю, где поставить точку ?

Comment: Правой кнопкой на родительской ноде в дереве и выбрать что-то типа Break on...